# All custom fields are missing in views 'add field' and 'add filter' forms (Drupal 7)

Tags: views, entities

I'm experiencing some very bizarre behaviour on a live website.

I've just added a new date field to a bunch of content types. I now need to add this as a filter criterion to a view. The problem is that when I go to add the filter, it doesn't show any custom fields at all in the Add Filter list, and this is the same for Add Field. It happens in all views.

The really strange thing is that I've copied the live database down to my local dev machine to debug, ensured that I have the live tag checked out, and on my local machine it works absolutely fine.

I've tried clearing caches, logging in as a different user, disabling a new custom module (which shouldn't make any difference). I just don't get what could be causing this, because the code and db are exactly the same in the live and local environments.

Almost certainly I'm overlooked something small. Can anyone think what it could be? Has anyone seem this weirdness before?

Thanks

Comment: Views UI sometimes breaks, for reasons that are not entirely clear to me. I'd start by checking for Javascript errors using Firebug or the equivalent for your browser.

Comment: Thanks @Alfred, I already looked at this though, no JS errors and the JSON that is being returned is what is being displayed, i.e. no custom fields. So it's somewhere on the back end

Comment: One reason for differences between sites is that order of execution is not always strictly determinate. Sometimes it depends on database results which might be ordered differently depending on arbitrary factors (two items have the same weight, for example). Not sure how to diagnose this offhand, though.

Comment: In the end I solved this by disabling views caching, adding the new filters/fields and re-enabling it (when the custom fields promptly disappeared again). Still very weird, when I just cleared the caches it made no difference. Must be something to do with the cache settings on our live envt. Thanks Alfred for your input.

Answer (score 3):

To add to james-geldart's answer, I solved this same problem permanently (or for a few hours so far at least) by deleting every row of the table cache_views in the site's database.